# How to get a client computer identifier in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net

Who can tell me how/whether I can get a client computer identifier in my asp.net/or javascript ? (The client is in network not local Intranet)

(What is the client computer indentifier? I think such as: Client computer MAC Address, or any hardware GUID (like CPU, Network Card, etc. )  ?)

Or whether any simplitify method to do it in HTML5?

Or whether I can get the client computer indentifier through ActiveX? (And how can i do use ActiveX, anyone who can give me some references, if the activeX can use C# to build is nice. )

(This is a business system, and customer is approved us to get their client computer hardware identifier, so how can i do in asp.net? )

Comment: I think there actually is a way to get the name of the client computer only if it on the local network using DNS

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script it might require authentication from the user to run ActiveX and ActiveX as far as i know only works in IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE  HTML  PUBLIC  "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
      <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1">
            <meta name="vs_targetSchema" content="http://schemas.
microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5">
            <script id="clientEventHandlersJS" language="javascript">
<!--

function Button1_onclick() {
      var locator = new ActiveXObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
      var service = locator.ConnectServer(".");
      var properties = service.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
      var e = new Enumerator (properties);
      document.write("<table border=1>");
      dispHeading();
      for (;!e.atEnd();e.moveNext ())
      {
            var p = e.item ();
            document.write("<tr>");
            document.write("<td>" + p.Caption + "</td>");
            document.write("<td>" + p.IPFilterSecurityEnabled + "</td>");
            document.write("<td>" + p.IPPortSecurityEnabled + "</td>");
            document.write("<td>" + p.IPXAddress + "</td>");
            document.write("<td>" + p.IPXEnabled + "</td>");
            document.write("<td>" + p.IPXNetworkNumber + "</td>");
            document.write("<td>" + p.MACAddress + "</td>");
            document.write("<td>" + p.WINSPrimaryServer + "</td>");
            document.write("<td>" + p.WINSSecondaryServer + "</td>");
            document.write("</tr>");
      }
      document.write("</table>");
}

function dispHeading()
{
      document.write("<thead>");
      document.write("<td>Caption</td>");
      document.write("<td>IPFilterSecurityEnabled</td>");
        document.write("<td>IPPortSecurityEnabled</td>");
        document.write("<td>IPXAddress</td>");
      document.write("<td>IPXEnabled</td>");
      document.write("<td>IPXNetworkNumber</td>");
      document.write("<td>MACAddress</td>");
      document.write("<td>WINSPrimaryServer</td>");
      document.write("<td>WINSSecondaryServer</td>");
      document.write("</thead>");
}

//-->
            </script>
      </head>
      <body>
            <INPUT id="Button1" type="button" value="Button" 
name="Button1" language="javascript" onclick="return Button1_onclick()">
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thank your apply, when I copy above code to a notepad, and save as "index.html", and opened it in IE9, after I clicked the button on the page, the page display nothing except a js error: Error: Object expected

Comment: You might have activex turned off

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, I have test above code, cool, it's run very well in local intranet, but unfortunately, when i upload it to remote server, and I opened the website, it display nothing, and in some pc client, the website shows js error on page: Automation server can't create object: Line 11. Could you help me opened the test website to look up where is mistake? The test Url is : http://www.codefw.com/test2 Thank you!